# What is the .get type of checkbox

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i'm trying to save user data to a database. There is 2 checkboxes teacher and student but there is only one table.
the table is looks like this

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_USER ="CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_USER + " ( " +
            USER_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
            NAME + " TEXT, " +
            PASSWORD + " TEXT, " +
            TYPE + " TEXT " + ")";
```

this is the insert method

```
 public boolean registeruser(String name, String password, String type) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(PASSWORD, password);
        contentValues.put(TYPE, type);

        long result = db.insert(TABLE_USER, null, contentValues);
        return result != -1;
    }
```

when i'm calling the `registeruser` db function i have to declare a type but the type is 2 checkboxes how can i mention it in here

Comment: You probably mean `isChecked();`. See the documentation here: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/checkbox#java

Comment: isChecked() method to Checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `isChecked()` of the `CheckBox` class returns `true` or `false`.
I guess you want to save `"Teacher"` or `"Student"` in the table:

```
db.registeruser(
    username.getText().toString(), 
    password.getText().toString(), 
    teacher.isChecked() ? "Teacher" : (student.isChecked() ? "Student" : "N/A")
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @eyllanesc is right. The isChecked() method will either return true or false depending on the value of the checkbox. There is no text to use getText() in a checkbox.
The syntax should be
**teacher.isChecked().toString()**